# Upload File With MetaData Fields

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, metadata, sharepoint-2013

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("URLSHAREPOINT"))
            {
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

                foreach (char c in "PASSWORD".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("USERNAME.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
                Web web = clientContext.Web; 
                FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"FILELOCATION");
                newFile.Url = "file uploaded via client OM.txt";
                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("LIBRARYNAME");
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I'am Upload files to my Sharepoint 365 Acount with the code above !
But I need to add Some metadata too

Can someone Help Me To add Metadata using my corrent Code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
                clientContext.Load(docList);
                clientContext.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("METADATANAME"));
                clientContext.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("METADATANAME"));
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                var Nome = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("METADATANAME").InternalName;
                var Posicao = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("METADATANAME").InternalName;
                uploadFile.ListItemAllFields[Nome] = "VALUE";
                uploadFile.ListItemAllFields[Posicao] = "VALUE";
                uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This is working ! Hope to Help Some one with this =)